# How to run macro based on content of the cell

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I'm looking for some assisting on how to trigger continuation of macro based on the value of a cell please.

What I'm hoping for is that when cell A1 = cell B1, I need it to perform a task, otherwise end script.

I assume this would be a simple `If... Then` script? Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This sort of thing is usually done by writing an event handler for the `Worksheet_Change` event. It is easy to find various examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way it can be done, this is assuming that all of your values are already there and you are running a check, rather than someone typing live in which case John's would be a good way to go.  However the one thing I don't like about worksheet_change is that once the macro is executed you can't hit undo.  I added in if length > 0, as if you have two empty cells it would still trigger.

```
Sub TestValues()

'Define variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

'Set variables
Set rng = Range("A1:A10")

'Begin
For Each cell In rng
    If Len(cell) > 0 Then
        If cell.Value = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            'Run macro
        End If
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

*Edit - I guess I didn't exactly read it right.  For some reason I was thinking you had a range of values to go through.  To do exactly what you asked for it would be more like this, sorry for the long post...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    If Len(Target) > 0 Then
        If Target.Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            'Run macro
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume your macro is in charge of changing A1 and/or B1 cells so that it really knows *when* to do that "continuation check".

In this case you can do that in multiple ways, here are two of them:

- keep "continuation" code inside your macro

  ```
  Sub main()

      ' your code till the statement that changes A1 and/or B1

      If Range("A1").Value <> Range("B1").Value Then Exit Sub '<-- if cells A1 and B1 DON'T have the same values then exit sub

      'here follows your code for the "Task"

  End Sub
  ```
- demand the Task to another `Sub`

  ```
  Sub main()

      ' your code till the statement that changes A1 and/or B1

      If Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value Then DoTask '<-- if cells A1 and B1 HAVE the same values then call 'DoTask()'
  End Sub


  Sub DoTask()
      ' here your code code for the "Task"
  End Sub
  ```

  in this latter case you may want to pass one (or more) parameter from "Main" macro to `DoTask`

  ```
  Sub main()

      ' your code till the statement that changes A1 and/or B1

      If Range("A1").Value = Range("B1").Value Then DoTask Range("A1").Value '<-- if cells A1 and B1 HAVE the same values then call 'DoTask  passing A1 cell value as "argument"
  End Sub


  Sub DoTask(val As Variant) '<--| DoTask accepts a parameter declared as of Variant type (but you may choose a more proper one
      ' here your code code for the "Task"
      ' it will use 'val'
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: @kitarika, did you get through it?